# How to resolve 404 not found error nginx on Docker container

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile

The objective is to run a basic html file on a Docker container.

Issue reproduction:
Here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY . /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Here is the repository for the index.html file - https://github.com/LaVie-environment/staplepage. The index.html file is in the same directory as the Dockerfile. Their parent directory is a portal directory. The portal directory contains the Dockerfile and index.html file.

Run below docker commands:

```
docker build -t webserver .
docker run -d -p 80:80 webserver
```

curl http://localhost:80

It displayed 404 page not found.

Comment: Tried to reproduce the issue but couldn't, is working fine. Check that index or directory is readable by the user running nginx process, which I can see it's the nginx user with id `101`

Comment: thanks @HernanGarcia please you mentioned that I should check whether the directory is readable by the user running nginx process, please how can I check this?

Comment: execute `docker run -it container /bin/sh` and check changing ownership using chown and permissions using chmod and make sure that user can read those files. hope this helps!

Comment: Do you had config the nginx website?